# Django Not Permitting POSTs From Google Web Toolkit

Tags: django, gwt

I'm trying to get Google Web Toolkit to work with Django through GETs and POSTs, following the examples [here](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.http.client.html). When GWT sends a POST, however, Django sends back an HTTP 403.

My question is then, is Django set up to not receive POSTs? Is there some setting I need to change? Or is there something wrong with the way GWT is sending the POST?

The GET is working either, if anyone also knows something about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From django1.2, views are [csrf](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) protected.

If you want to csrf exempt any view use [`csrf_exempt`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#exceptions) decorator